# Solving for upper bound of integral with known value

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the upper bound of an integral. My current code is

```
f[r_?NumericQ] = 
(1/(Pi*a^3))*4*Pi*(r^2)*E^(-r/a);
Plot[f[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

When I evaluate this, the graph is incorrect. The current graph and error I'm getting are
[image: error graph]

last night, however, I was able to get the graph to look like this
[image: good code]

What changed? Why isn't the current code working? Alternatively, are there other ways to do this calculation?

EDIT: Using the code given I redid my calculations. The new code is

```
a = 5.291*10^-11;

f[r_] = (1/(Pi*a^3))*4*Pi*(r^2)*E^(-r/a);

Plot[f[r], {r, 0, 1}]
  clear[b]
  g[b_] = Integrate[f[r], {r, 0, b}]
sol = g[b] /. sol
NSolve[{g[b] == 1/2, b > 0}, b][[1]]
```

the output is

> 8. +(-8.-1.512*10^11 b-1.42884*10^21 b^2) E^(-1.89*10^10 b)
>      ReplaceAll::reps: {sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
>      $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of >8. +(-8.-1.512*10^11 b-1.42884*10^21 b^2) E^(-1.89*10^10 b).
>      Hold[8. +(-8.-1.512*10^11 b-1.42884*10^21 b^2) E^(-1.89*10^10 b)/. sol]

Comment: you need a and b constants

Comment: Please use an *informative* title, that will help others find solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved exactly. The integral is:

```
f[r_] := (1/(Pi*a^3))*4*Pi*(r^2)*E^(-r/a)

int = Integrate[f[r], {r, 0, b}]
```

> 8 - (4 (2 a^2 + 2 a b + b^2) E^(-(b/a)))/a^2

Let $b = s a$:

```
scaledint = int /. b->a s //Simplify
```

> 8 - 4 E^-s (2 + 2 s + s^2)

Set this result to $1/2$ and solve for `s`:

```
rt = s /. First @ Solve[scaledint == 1/2 && s>0, s]
```

> Root[{16 - 15 E^#1 + 16 #1 + 8 #1^2 &, 0.89782942356979330033}]

So, the dependence of `b` on `a` is:

```
b[a_] = a rt;
```

Compare with @Bob's answer:

```
b[1/2]
%//N
```

> 1/2 Root[{16 - 15 E^#1 + 16 #1 + 8 #1^2 &, 0.89782942356979330033}]
>
> 0.448915

and:

```
b[5291 10^-14]
%//N
```

> (5291 Root[{16 - 15 E^#1 + 16 #1 + 8 #1^2 &, 
>      0.89782942356979330033}])/100000000000000
>
> 4.75042*10^-11

Answer (score 1):

Since the definition of `f` does not use numeric techniques (e.g., [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html), [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html), [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)) , there is no reason to restrict its argument to being numeric by using [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html). However, in order to [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), the parameter `a` must have a numeric value which you presumably defined but did not provide.

It appears that you used

```
a = 1/2;

f[r_] = (1/(Pi*a^3))*4*Pi*(r^2)*E^(-r/a);

Plot[f[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[b]
```

`f` can be integrated analytically so use of `NIntegrate` is unnecessary.

```
g[b_] = Integrate[f[r], {r, 0, b}]

(* 8 + 8 (-1 - 2 b (1 + b)) E^(-2 b) *)
```

The equation `g[b] == 1/2` can be solved using [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) provided that you restrict `b` to be positive. This avoids use of [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) and the need to provide an initial estimate.

```
sol = NSolve[{g[b] == 1/2, b > 0}, b][[1]]

(* {b -> 0.448915} *)
```

Verifying

```
g[b] /. sol

(* 0.5 *)
```

**EDIT:** For the revised value of `a`

```
a = 5291*10^-14;

f[r_] = (1/(Pi*a^3))*4*Pi*(r^2)*E^(-r/a);
```

For `a` with such a small value, the values of `E^(-r/a)` are too small to evaluate. `Plot` the `Log` of `f`

```
logf[r_] = Log[f[r]] // PowerExpand // FullSimplify

(* -((100000000000000 r)/5291) + 44 Log[2] + 42 Log[5] - 3 Log[5291] + 2 Log[r] *)

Plot[logf[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[b]
g[b_] = Integrate[f[r], {r, 0, b}]

(* 8 - (1/27994681)
 8 (27994681 + 
    100000000000000 b (5291 + 50000000000000 b)) E^(-100000000000000 b/5291) *)
```

You did not copy the code correctly. If done properly,

```
sol = NSolve[{g[b] == 1/2, b > 0}, b][[1]]

(* {b -> 4.75042*10^-11} *)
```

Verifying

```
g[b] /. sol

(* 0.5 *)
```

Comment: When I put in your suggestions, it removed the error message but now the solutions I get include b in them as opposed to giving me an output of a value for b.

Comment: If you use the code that I posted you should get the results that I show. If not, start with a fresh kernel. If after a restart you still are having problems post the **code** (not an image).